# Don't escape back slash in variable from database

Tags: c#, .net

In database i have record with

```
value = "\\testapp\wwwroot\CmsUploads"
```

but in c# it is converted to `"\\\\testapp\\wwwroot\\CmsUploads"`. The problem is that now I cannot use this value as

```
string path = valueFromDb;
new Root(new DirectoryInfo(path)
```

I always get directory must exist exception. How i can solve this problem?

Comment: C# never converts backslashes. Something else is happening. The debugger displays extra backslashes.

Comment: What do you mean by in c# it is converted to "\\\\testapp\\wwwroot\\CmsUploads"? If you inspect a string in the VS IDE, you will always see characters escaped; a single backslash in a text string (such as a Windows path delimiter) will appear doubled because that's what it would look like if you were to hard-code the string in your source. Perhaps the "directory must exist" error is due to some other cause (like a network problem) than incorrect use of backslashes.

Comment: If you hover over it in debug to inspect the value, click on the magnifying glass to see the value properly.

Comment: Yes it was just network problems :)